# If $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=a$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a_k}{n+1}=a$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

I did the following

**Problem:** Let $(a_n)$ be a convergent sequence with $\lim_{n \to\infty} a_n=a$ then the sequence $(b_n)$ defined by $b_n:=\frac{1}{n+1}(a_0+a_1+...+a_n)$ also converges to $a$.

Since I came up with a different solution to one given, I post it here and ask if this is correct.

**Solution:** We can rewrite the defintion of $b_n$ to $b_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a_k}{n+1}$. Now we show that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with

\begin{align}|b_n-a|&=|\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a_k}{n+1} -a|\\
&=|\frac{1}{n+1}\left( \sum_{k=0}^n a_k -\sum_{k=0}^n a\right) |\\
&\le\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n | a_k - a |\\
&<\epsilon\end{align}

if $n\ge N$.

Now since $(a_n)$ is convergent and bounded, there exists a $M$ with

$$k\ge M \implies |a_k-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
$$k < M \implies |a_k-a|\le M_k$$

It follows that

\begin{align}\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n | a_k - a |\\
&=\frac{1}{n+1}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{M-1} | a_k - a | -\sum_{k=m}^{n} | a_k - a |\right)\\
&\le\frac{M}{n+1} M_k +\frac{(n-M)}{n+1}\frac{\epsilon}{2}\end{align}

Then, there exists a $N>M$ so that $n \ge N\implies \frac{M}{n+1} M_k<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and we have

$$\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n | a_k - a |<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon$$

which shows, that $(b_n)$ is convergent. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Your proof looks unnecessarily long to me.

Comment: Looks good. Two very small mistakes: the sum from $k=0$ to $M-1$ has $M$ terms, so instead of $\frac{M-1}{n+1}M_k$ it should be $\frac{M}{n+1}M_k$. Also, why you propose that $N<M$? I don't see why that is true, and it also doesn't matter, since you can just assume $n\ge \text{max}(M,N)$ in the last step.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I disagree, intro proofs in analysis like this need to be fully fleshed out in details.

Comment: @RichardJensen, this was a typo. I corrected it to $N>M$. But I see your point. Thx!

Comment: I think I was mistaken. I thought it would be easy to write a quick and simple proof (with $3$ or $4$ lines) but I can't do it.